# Fetch PDF File from domain name url path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-pdf

**Trying to display the PDF File between "Download CV" and keep on getting the error message "Failed to load PDF file." Used the Fetch API to fetch PDF File from the domain name URL.
**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useContext } from 'react';
import '../../assets/css/resume.css';
import { greetings } from '../../data/portfolio';
import Particle from "../../helper/particle";
import { AiOutlineDownload } from "react-icons/ai";
import { Document, Page, pdfjs } from "react-pdf/dist/esm/entry.webpack";
import { Container } from '@mui/material';
import  Zoom  from 'react-reveal/Zoom';
import "react-pdf/dist/esm/Page/AnnotationLayer.css";
import { ThemeContext } from '../../context/themeContext';
import Responsive from 'react-responsive';

pdfjs.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = `//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/${pdfjs.version}/pdf.worker.min.js`;

const pdfUrl = "https://ooyebade.com/static/Oyindamola_Oyebade_Resume.pdf";

function useResume() {

    const [objectUrl, setObjectUrl] = useState(null);
  
    useEffect(() => {
  
      fetch(pdfUrl)
  
        .then(response => response.blob())
  
        .then(blob => {
  
          const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  
         setObjectUrl(url);
  
        })
  
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
  
    }, []);
  
    return objectUrl;
}

const Resume = () => {
  
    const [numPages, setNumPages] = useState(null);
  
    const { theme } = useContext(ThemeContext);
  
    const pdf = pdfUrl;
  
    const isDesktop = Responsive({ minWidth: 786 });


   return (
            
    <div style={{ backgroundColor: theme.secondary }}>

        <section className="service-container">
            <title>Elizabeth's Portfolio | Resume </title>
            <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
            <Particle />
            <Container className="container">
                <Zoom left cascade>
                    <div className="one">
                        <span className="heading">Resume</span>
                    </div>
                </Zoom>

                <div className='resume-btn'>
                    {greetings.resumePdf && (
                        <a
                            href={pdf}
                            download='resume'
                            target='_blank'
                            rel='noreferrer'
                            style={{ maxWidth: "250px" }}
                        >
                        <button className='main-btn'>
                            <AiOutlineDownload />
                                Download CV
                            </button>
                        </a>
                    )}
                </div>

                <Document file={pdf} onLoadSuccess={({ numPages }) => setNumPages(numPages)}>
                    {Array(numPages).fill().map((_, i) => (
                    <Page key={`page_${i + 1}`} pageNumber={i + 1} scale={isDesktop ? 1.7 : 0.6} />
                    ))}
                </Document>
                
                <div className='resume-btn'>
                    {greetings.resumePdf && (
                        <a
                            href={pdf}
                            download='resume'
                            target='_blank'
                            rel='noreferrer'
                            style={{ maxWidth: "250px" }}
                        >
                        <button className='main-btn'>
                            <AiOutlineDownload />
                                Download CV
                            </button>
                        </a>
                    )}
                </div>
            </Container>
        </section>
    </div>
   )
}

export default Resume;
```

Error Message:

[image]

I'm also using react-pdf. I've tried to use the fetch api to try and fetch the pdf file from the domain name url. I was expecting something like this:
[image]

Comment: Log the actual error in your code base, and share that here